# The most efficient 3sum algorithm using python for the leetcode challenge

Tags: python

I am not able to pass the time limit test in leetcode for the 3sum problem using Python. Has anyone been able to do that? Thanks!

My existing code:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """

        solution=[]

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            tmp={}
            for j in range(1+i,len(nums)):
                if -(nums[j]+nums[i]) in tmp:
                    solution.append(tuple(sorted((nums[j],nums[i],-(nums[j]+nums[i])))))
                else:
                    tmp[nums[j]]=j

        return list(set(solution))
```

Comment: describe what the 3sums problem is, _we aren't psychic_

Comment: I googled 3sum. I regret it...

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/description/

Comment: @FHTMitchell oh my god, this is NSFW lol

Comment: I have a solution which is accepted but it's so kludgy that I don't want to show it. But since leetcode is so accomodating that it shows you the latest input when it fails, you have something to work with locally, don't you?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Yes, I have the input code. The input code has a len of 3000. It take a couple of sec for my local machine to churn out the result, but leetcode gives me a "time limited exceeded" error which normally means my code is not efficient yet.

Comment: The time limit seems to be around one second, so work some more.

Answer (score 0):

No idea whats wrong with your solution. I think the trick is to treat the result objects as [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) which are called `collections.Counter` in python. We can also use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to do all the getting all combinations of 3 from the input.

```
import itertools
import collections

class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """

        res = []
        for t in itertools.combinations(nums, 3):
            if sum(t) == 0:
                c = collections.Counter(t)
                if c not in res:
                    res.append(c)
        return [list(t.elements()) for t in res]
```

---

Testing:

```
Solution().threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4])
# --> [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried collections as well, but it hit the time limit error at a test case with 128 len :(

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    
        items = len(nums)
        nums.sort()
        outputs = set()
        i = 0
        while i < items-2:
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]: 
                i += 1
                continue
            j = i+1
            k = items-1
            
            while j<k:
                sums = nums[j] + nums[i] + nums[k]
                if sums == 0: 
                    if (nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]) not in outputs:
                        outputs.add((nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]))
                        while j < k and nums[j] == nums[j+1]: j+=1
                        while k > j and nums[k] == nums[k-1]: k-=1
                    j += 1
                    k -= 1
                elif sums < 0: 
                    j+= 1
                    #while j < k and nums[j] == nums[j-1]: j+=1
                else:
                    k -= 1
                    #while k > j and nums[k] == nums[k+1]: k-=1

            i += 1
            
        return outputs
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is bit different:

```py
nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
mysum = 0
def threeSum(nums, mysum):
    data = nums
    result = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(data)):
            kdata = list(data)

            if j <= (len(data)):
                mys = (mysum - (data[i] + data[j]))
                datai = data[i] 
                dataj = data[j]
                kdata.pop(i)
                kdata.pop(j - 1)
                if mys in kdata:
                    ss = [mys, datai, dataj]
                    ss.sort()
                    if ss not in result:
                        result.append(ss)

        
    print(result)
threeSum(nums, mysum)
```

Result:

```
[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

May not be the efficient one, yet it's simple.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
val = 9

class ThreeSum:
    def solve(self, arr, val):
        res = []
        for i, v1 in enumerate(arr):
            for j, v2 in enumerate(arr):
                for k, v3 in enumerate(arr):
                    if i != j  != k != i:
                        if v1+v2+v3 == val:
                            res.append([v1, v2, v3])
        return res

print(ThreeSum().solve(arr, val))
# (1, 2, 6)
```

Glad it helps!
Comment if there's any doubt.

Comment: Shouldn't it produce (2, 3, 4) too? And it's probably even slower than the asker's code.

Comment: Thanks. The 3 loops can work, but it runs slower than using the 2 loops and a dictionary.